# object of type 'float' has no len() on a string object

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to convert a column in my dataframe, the name of the column is 'Weight', it has value in `str` format

eg: `"175lbs"`

I'm using a mapper to convert all these values to `float`

I tried lambda function using a mapper

```
def WeightConverter(w):
    return float(w[:len(w)-3])

df1['Weight'] = df1.Weight.map(lambda x : WeightConverter(x))
df1['Weight'].head()
```

However, `type(df1['Weight'][0])` returns `str`. Expected result: `175.0` of type `float`

Comment: df1 is my dataframe

Comment: In `WeightConverter` you could just use `return float(w[:-3])`, but otherwise this works for me.

Comment: Try with apply instead map

Comment: any examples for using apply ansev

Comment: 'float' object is not subscriptable when doing return float(w[:-3])

Comment: Seems, some values are already float - `return float(w[:-3]) if not isinstance(w, float) else w`

Answer (score 4):

Try using regex to extract your numbers first, then you can do any further operations.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Weight' : np.random.randint(0,250,size=500)})
df['Weight'] = df['Weight'].astype(str) + 'lbs'
print(df.head(10))
   Weight
0  224lbs
1   11lbs
2  218lbs
3  132lbs
4   55lbs
5   87lbs
6   62lbs
7    4lbs
8   38lbs
9  218lbs
```

then use `(\d+)` with `str.extract`

```
df['Weight_Float'] = df['Weight'].str.extract(r'(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)').astype(float)
    print(df.head(10))
     Weight  Weight_Float
0  119lbs         119.0
1    7lbs           7.0
2  241lbs         241.0
3   85lbs          85.0
4  144lbs         144.0
5  219lbs         219.0
6  160lbs         160.0
7  173lbs         173.0
8  166lbs         166.0
9   35lbs          35.0
```

## Explanation:

- `(` start a capture group
- `\d` a shorthand character class, which matches all numbers; it is the
  same as [0-9]
- `+` one or more of the expression
- `)` end a capture group

Comment: will this work if the string is 119.20lbs and the required output is 119.20

Comment: @GaneshRam I've edited the regex to extract floating point numbers for you.